Test python application and SQL scripts
I am creating application with Flask and I am using SQLAclhemy with it.
I am currently writing some unit/integration test and I was wondering what is the best practise when it comes to add data to my inmemory db in python? Should I execute SQL scripts before I run my tests in a file? Should I execute SQL during the test?
For instance let's take a loot at my register methods test which are in my test_auth.py file (there is the register method and the login method):
def test_register(client):
    data = {
        "username" : "test_user",
        "password" : "test_password"
    }
    response = client.post(f'{AUTH_ROUTE}register', json=data)
    assert response.status_code == 201

    assert response.get_json() == {'message': 'User created successfully'}

    with client.application.app_context():
        user = User.query.filter_by(username='test_user').first()
        assert user is not None
        assert user.username == 'test_user'
        assert user.password == 'test_password'

def test_register_user_already_exist(client):
    with client.application.app_context():
        existing_user = User(username='test_user', password='password')
        db.session.add(existing_user)
        db.session.commit()
    data = {
        "username" : "test_user",
        "password" : "test_password"
    }
    response = client.post(f'{AUTH_ROUTE}register', json=data)
    assert response.status_code == 400


I am writing code with app_context() to execute operation on my DB. Is it correct way to do the things? Should I remove the SQL part and put it in other place?
Should I execute a script first that do my SQL for the test_auth part then run all the tests?

I would include any setup (and teardown) steps in your test script. This will ensure that your tests are reproducible, and will be the same when you make changes to your codebase and test the changed code.
It also ensures that if your code makes changes to the database, your tests are always starting from the same database state.
